# Azure API Management proactively invalidate and refresh cache

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

In APIM is it possible to proactively invalidate and refresh the cache using a policy, so that users never experience a cache miss and the latest data is populated in the cache? We have a request that's taking awhile to come back, so we never want to have the client wait for it.

There's a request to invalidate the cache based on post/put operations, which would be perfect: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/13428855-invalidate-cache-based-on-other-operations

Unfortunately, it's 2 years old and still under review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom caching to store and update value. You can use Azure functions to schedule a timer to call an api in APIM for updating cache.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-sample-cache-by-key

Comment: That would work if the cache uses a sliding expiration instead of absolute. Do you know if that's the case with APIM?

Comment: Actually if it were sliding expiration the cache would never get updated if it were paired with a timer that called it before it expires, right? We would need a way to invalidate the cache as well.

Comment: cache-store-value policy works by absolute expiration time. You will have to use cache-remove-value policy to remove cache for invalidation.


Steps
1. Timer pings api - refreshCache every 4 mins.
2. refreshCache api uses cache-store-value policy to update all keys, duration 5 mins.
3. If POST/PUT calls happen which requires cache invalidation. A policy can be added for those operations to update (refresh) or remove cache keys.

Comment: Thanks, JJ I'll give this a try.

Comment: @JoeyEng how did you solve this finally?

Comment: I believe I followed the advice of the previous comment to use cache-store-value to update cache values